# Firestore console gets open up whenever I try to open a particular document on Firestore. Happens only when I click on a particular document

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **Firestore** for my android application. Some user has created few documents in it from the android app and **whenever I try to click that document the Firebase reloads** and opens the firebase console and dont let me read those documents.

This happens only in these documents, all other documents can be read but something is wrong with these documents' Ids. I am uploading a screen shot below showing those 4 documents which have this problem and the last document in screenshot is working fine.

[image]

**I have already tried to delete those weird document using the code but they do not get deleted**. I have noticed that the document's Id is having a space. But I have tried to create a similar document with same document ID but it is working fine.

There are 7 fields inside each document of which 6 are created by code and user can change only one field. The 5 fields are normal strings and 1 field is TimeStamp storing when the document is created. The last field stores what user was trying to search in the application and I have also used that field as Document Id with adding an extra random String along with it. Read example below to get clear:

Suppose user searched in the app: chalo mana ganga

When he/she presses back button a document is created and stored in firestore having 5 fields which are strings and 1 field of current time. And last field storing user's search string.
**Id of document created: chalomanaganga (what user searched) + randomStringGeneratedByApp**

**The random string contains only numbers and alphabets and there is no space in whole document Id.** I cant understand why the below 3 document Ids are having space and they do not open.

I am pasting the 3 document IDs which are causing this problem:

**chalomanagangsaminathere 581333**

**chalomanagangsaminathere 8473IR**

**chalomanagangsaminathere CZfPZF**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this bug to Firebase feedback and support and the bug was removed in my end. If anyone also faces this problem try to write the bug report to Firebase support and they will resolve it within a week.